# Escalar VideoView al máximo

Tags: android, android-fragment, videoview

como puedo hacer para que mi video se muestre en su tamaño máximo de forma proporcionada es decir que sus bordes choquen con los bordes de la pantalla, "no me refiero  a pantalla completa".

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">                   
                           

                            
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Texto One"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

     </LinearLayout>

     <VideoView
         android:id="@+id/videoView2"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="500dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Así esta en la parte de "desing", agregue el cuadro marrón para indicar que así aparece al correr la app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo que quede con la parte GRIS pero al momento de ejecutarla app me aparece con la parte marrón. Espero se halla entendido mi idea "Deseo que el video se ajuste completamente a la pantalla, sin que pierda su proporción, o talvez que se recorte un poco pero que tome toda la pantalla en relacion a los bordes  horizontales ya que un video en formato horizontal si logra visualizarse como deseo es decir sus bordes horizontales chocan con los bordes de la pantalla", aclaro que no me refiero a que se reproduzca en pantalla completa.

Intente con match_parent en layout_width y layout_height igual con wrap_content pero no funciona,alintentar con estos en la parte visualse puede notar que no agrega ningún contenedor solo se encoje.
Para las imágenes uso esta propiedad, pero esta no esta disponible para VideoView

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Me encuentro en un fragmento aunque no creo que esto sea relevante en este caso.

Comment: Pude solucionarlo colocando mi videoView en un ConstrainLayout, y agregando en layout_height = 900dp, ya que cuando colocaba 500 al haber un video con mayor tamaño lo distorsionaba

Comment: Hay alguna otra mejor forma de hacerlo? Por que al utilizar layout_width = match_pared o wrap_content el contenedor se encogía, se  convertia en una linea.

Comment: debes colocarlo en un ConstrainLayout, agregarle constraints en los 4 lados y poner layout_width y layout_height en 0. Si muestras tu xml completo puedo mostrarte como hacerlo.